# Google BigQuery optimization with subquery in WHERE clause

Tags: google-bigquery

I am attempting to set up a query that selects a subset of data from a range of daily partitions of Google Analytics session data and writes the data to a Google BigQuery staging table. The challenge for me is to reduce the processing cost when using a subquery in the WHERE clause.

Google Analytics data from the query are to be appended to a staging table before being processed and loaded into the target data table (my-data-table). The main query is given in two forms below. The first is hard-coded. The second reflects the preferred form. The upper bound on _TABLE_SUFFIX is hard-coded for both to simplify the query. The objective is to use MAX(date), where date has the form YYYYMMDD, from my-data-table as a lower bound on the ga_sessions_* daily partitions. The query has been simplified for presentation here but is believed to contain all necessary elements.

The aggregate query (SELECT MAX(date) FROM `my-project-12345.dataset.my-data-table`) returns the value '20201015' and processes 202 KB. Depending upon whether I use the returned value explicitly (as '20201015') in the WHERE clause of the main query or use the SELECT MAX() query in the WHERE clause, there is a significant difference in data processed between the two queries (2.3 GB for the explicit value vs 138.1 GB for the SELECT MAX() expression).

Is there an optimization, plan, or directive that can be applied to the preferred form of the main query that will reduce the data processing cost? Thank you for any assistance that can be provided.

**Main Query (hard-coded version, processes 2.3 GB)**

```
SELECT
  GA.date, 
  GA.field1, 
  hits.field2, 
  hits.field3
FROM 
  `my-project-12345.dataset.ga_sessions_*` AS GA, UNNEST(GA.hits) AS hits
WHERE 
  hits.type IN ('PAGE', 'EVENT')
  AND hits.field0 = 'some value'
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX > '20201015'
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20201025'
```

**Main Query (preferred form, processes 138.1 GB without optimization)**

```
SELECT
  GA.date, 
  GA.field1, 
  hits.field2, 
  hits.field3
FROM 
  `my-project-12345.dataset.ga_sessions_*` AS GA, UNNEST(GA.hits) AS hits
WHERE 
  hits.type IN ('PAGE', 'EVENT')
  AND hits.field0 = 'some value'
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX > (SELECT MAX(date) FROM `my-project-12345.dataset.my-data-table`)
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20201025'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scripting for this

The "trick" is in pre-computing

```
DECLARE start_date STRING;
SET start_date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM `my-project-12345.dataset.my-data-table`);
```

and assigning to variable and then use this variable in where clause on main query - in this case it will use cost effective version

```
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX > start_date
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20201025'
```

Comment: Thank you for directing me to using variables. Adding 'variable' to my searches provides more information. I'll try it out.

Comment: Declaring and setting the start_date variable precludes using the 'Query settings' or 'Schedule query' configuration to specify the destination table for the query output. CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE <staging_table> AS SELECT... should do it.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE does not work in a script: configuration.query.writeDisposition cannot be set for scripts

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE gives the error message noted above (configuration.query.writeDisposition cannot be set for scripts). I had included the objective of writing the data to a staging table in the opening description of the problem. I'll follow up. Thanks.

Comment: Likewise, if you feel that the question is a good one, I welcome the feedback.